# WebService testing using SOAPUI

Tags: testing, web-services, soap

I am currently working as functional tester. I have been assigned to do web services testing for a project. The test strategy is something like this:

- our company is switching vendors who provide a service by accessing data in our company's system
- the new vendor should be able to search for a particular data in our system through web service call, which is to be tested in QA environment.
- I should use SOAPUI to test this: to send a request and validate the response.

My questions are as follows:

- I know we can generate test cases in SOAPUI, but how to write test cases for web services testing in a document? (like the way we document functional tests)
- Is there a way where we can call our company's QA url into SOAPUI and pass required input and check for desired output? Or it should be done only by passing a WSDL file into SOAPUI and give input and get desired output?
- Based on the above info, please explain where I should start and how the process should flow till finish.

Comment: [Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Answer (score 0):

you can create soapui test cases using the Structuring and Running Tests.

More info [SOAPUI Testcase Samples](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html)

URL can be passed to SOAPUI, and the data can be stored in XML, but i have not done input/output on the results.